# Play custom notification sound approximately of 10 seconds when the application is in terminated mode and the device is silent

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications, avfoundation

I want to play a custom notification sound minimum of 10 seconds when the application is in terminated mode and the device is silent.

**The scenario which is working:-**

1. Can play custom notification sound when the application is in terminated mode.
2. Can play custom notification sound when the device is silent and in foreground or background.

**The scenario which is not working:-**

1. The device is in silent mode and the application is in terminated mode, I receive a push notification and it just vibrates, I want to play the same sound which I am doing in all the above other scenarios.

**I want this for an emergency situation.**

Comment: can you show the payload?

Comment: let aps : [String : Any] = [
            "alert": messageAlert,
            "badge": 1,
            "sound": "siren.mp3"
        ]
        
        let apns : [String : Any] = [
            "aps": aps ,
            "title": "my title",
            "apns-priority": 10,
            "pn_ttl": 30
        ]

There is no issue with the push notification I am able to play the custom sound. Please let me know if there is any issue with the payload.
The only scenario in which custom sound not working is when an application is in terminated mode and device is in silent mode.

Comment: try 1 thing send "content-available = 1" in the payload and see if it works.

Comment: No this is not working and I cannot use this.